# Ruby RSPEC test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rubygems

I would like to know how to satisfy the `is_valid` test, I tried it in several ways but the test does not pass what I have to write in the class

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe PixKey do
  subject(:pix_key) { described_class.new(key) }

  let(:key) { 'email@wesley.io' }

  describe '.new' do
    context 'with a valid key' do
      it { is_expected.to be_a(described_class) }

      it { is_expected.to be_valid }
    end
```

Cod class

```
class PixKey

  attr_accessor :key

  def new(key)
    @key = :key
    validates :key, presence: true
  end

end
```

Err

> PixKey   .new
> with a valid key
> is expected to be a kind of PixKey

```
  is expected to be valid (FAILED - 1)
```

Comment: Your class code doesn't make much sense. Check out [Getting Started with Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) (in particular [Generating a Model](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#mvc-and-you-generating-a-model)) and [Active Record Basics](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).

Comment: Stefan, good morning!
I would like to know what I have to pass inside the Method of the class for the test to pass, I know that class doesn't make sense.
Thanks

Comment: Hence the links, they explain how to set up a model and how to add validation.

Comment: ok i will try it, sorry for my ignorance i'm a beginner

Comment: BTW, support for Rails 4 ended in 2017. Unless you are maintaining a legacy project, you should use / learn a recent version, i.e. Rails 6 or Rails 7.

Comment: ok already installed the latest version of rails

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Do you want to create a class to store data in the database (an `ActiveRecord` model in Rails language)? Or do you want to create a stand-alone pure Ruby class that offers come validation?

Comment: that's right I actually wanted to do a pure validation not ruby ​​but I couldn't satisfy this be_valid and also when I try to use activerrecord it returns an error

Comment: First you have to _decide_ what you want to do. There are plain Ruby classes (as shown in your example code) that don't have built-in validation. Then there's [Active Model](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html) which you have to `include` and finally there's the database-backed [Active Record](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) which works by inheriting from `ApplicationRecord`.

Comment: When I try to enter :

include ActiveModel::Validations

return this error:

Uncaught exception: uninitialized constant PixKey::ActiveModel

    include ActiveModel::Validations

Comment: Try including it like this `include ::ActiveModel::Validations`. This will let the ruby know that `ActiveModel` is in base scope and not inside `PixKey` scope.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is a test driven development (TDD) assignment where you got some specs and have to implement a class that passes the tests.

In order to get your specs green, you have to implement some methods. To do so, you have to understand RSpec's syntax:

- [`described_class`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/metadata/described-class) – this is whatever comes after `describe`. In your spec, it's `describe PixKey`, so `described_class.new(key)` is equivalent to `PixKey.new(key)`
- `be_a` is a [type matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-11/docs/built-in-matchers/type-matchers) and equivalent to calling [`kind_of?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Object.html#kind_of-3F-method)
- `be_valid` is a [predicate matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-11/docs/built-in-matchers/predicate-matchers) and equivalent to calling `valid?`

---

Let's start with an empty class:

```
class PixKey
end
```

Running the specs gives an error: ([`--fail-fast`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-11/docs/command-line/fail-fast-option) makes RSpec stop after the first failing spec)

```
$ rspec pix_key_spec.rb --fail-fast

Failures:

  1) PixKey.new with a valid key
     Failure/Error: subject(:pix_key) { described_class.new(key) }

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

❌ 1 example, 1 failure
```

RSpec called `PixKey.new(key)` but `new` doesn't take an argument. In order to get that working, you *could* implement a class method called `new`, i.e.:

```
class PixKey
  def self.new(key)
    allocate
  end
end
```

But Ruby classes already come with a built-in [`new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Class.html#new-method) method that handles the allocation for you. You typically just implement an instance method called `initialize`:

```
class PixKey
  def initialize(key)
  end
end
```

Ruby's built-in `new` will call `initialize` and pass all arguments to it.

Note that I don't do anything with `key` yet. This is a core part of TDD: you write just enough to get the test passing. Let's try it again:

```
$ rspec pix_key_spec.rb --fail-fast

Failures:

  1) PixKey.new with a valid key is expected to be valid
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to be_valid }
       expected #<PixKey:0x000000010201de90> to respond to `valid?`

❌ 2 examples, 1 failure
```

This time, it's complaining about our `PixKey` instance not responding to `valid?`, so let's implement that method: (the trailing `?` is part of the method name)

```
class PixKey
  def initialize(key)
  end

  def valid?
  end
end
```

And run the tests again:

```
$ rspec pix_key_spec.rb --fail-fast

Failures:

  1) PixKey.new with a valid key is expected to be valid
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to be_valid }
       expected `#<PixKey:0x00000001027b1da0>.valid?` to be truthy, got nil

❌ 2 examples, 1 failure
```

Now it says that our `valid?` method is expected to return a "truthy" result. In Ruby, everything besides `nil` and `false` qualifies as truthy, but I'd just just use `true`:

```
class PixKey
  def initialize(key)
  end

  def valid?
    true
  end
end
```

```
$ rspec pix_key_spec.rb --fail-fast

✅ 2 examples, 0 failures
```

At this point, the specs pass. But obviously, the class is far from complete: `key` is never used and `valid?` just always returns `true` without validating anything.

I assume that there are more tests to pass. Keep working in small steps, just one test at a time.